# Security headers not responding on Apache 2.4 Ubuntu 22.04 with PHP8.1-FPM HTTP/2

Tags: apache2, security, linux-headers

I have tried this:

1- `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

2- `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

3- `.htaccess or apache virtual host`

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

4- `.htaccess or apache virtual host`

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

5- `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I have also added `CGIPassAuth On` in `.htaccess` and `apache.conf` without luck.

I have also added the headers in the virtual host without luck.

Any idea on how to get the security headers to respond?

Thanks

Comment: Please add what you were expecting to get and what you actually got.

Comment: I expect not to get any missing headers on a testing site like this: https://securityheaders.com/

Comment: It's a known issue that different Apache mods block Security headers when using PHP-FPM. I just can't seem to find a way to auth them.